# Error oauth_problem when trying to Connect to Xero using method POST

Tags: apex, api, oauth, httprequest

Good day everyone, I am trying to connect to Xero using Salesforce Apex. I've found this link [Apex for Xero](https://github.com/benedwards44/Apex-for-Xero/) and find it very useful. Everything is working well when I use PUT and GET method. The problem I have is that, when I try to use POST method to update some Xero data, I get the error below :

> Error oauth_problem = signature_invalid & oauth_problem_advice =
>   Failed to validate signature

Does anyone here who already tried to connect to Xero ?

What is the possible reason for this kind of problem ?

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this ?

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you...

Comment: This issue is generally related to Public key mismatch. Have you installed correct public key as mentioned in the link?

Comment: @SarojBera Actually I think yes. It is because, I can connect to Xero using PUT and GET method.